# jQuery DatePicker not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello I'm trying to create a simple textbox with a datepicker that appears when a user clicks inside of the it.  I have the following loaded in my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/start/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script><!-- Was missing closing tag
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And in my body, I have the following textbox:

```
<body>

    <input id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker" type="text">

</body>
```

My problem is that when I try to click inside the text box, nothing happens.  I'm not sure what the problem might be.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

UPDATE:

Tried the CDN and also downloaded the entire jQuery UI package and still won't show.  Tried in both IE and Firefox.

UPDATE 2:

Was hoping that syntax error I corrected above would fix it, but no dice.

Comment: Your using a customized package for jQuery UI, are you sure it includes the datepicker requirements ?

Comment: I'll double-check, I'm looking at the small demo that comes with the downloadable, customized package and it shows up fine on there.  What are the datepicker requirements?

Answer (score 24):

jQuery UI adds the "hasDatepicker" class to the input after it is clicked. Try removing the hasDatepicker class. If you are using a jQuery selector such as $('.hasDatepicker') to select the input(s), try giving it another class name.

Answer (score 4):

Please remove the class hasDatepicker from input tag and it should work fine.

```
class = 'hasDatepicker' //Need to remove
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.

Open the stylesheet and find `.ui-helper-hidden-accessible`.

If there is a duplicate line for `clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);`, remove it (you may need to remove both).  This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: There was a duplicate line, but that didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CDN to test to make sure you have the complete jQuery UI.  Your calling it right...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple instances of the date picker try using a class rather than the ID, the reason being is the ID needs to be unique to the element or calling jQuery cannot run the function, this is because the function wont know what specific element on the page to place the script into.

The script would look like this

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And the element would look like this

```
<input id="myInput" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="text">
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'll have fixed this by now but here are a few things I would have tried:

Ensure you are grabbing jQuery followed by jQuery UI and a stylesheet for .datepicker exists.

Change it from looking for an ID to a class as datepicker puts its own ID in.

If it was on a click event make sure that a datepicker has not previously been applied to the element (so a new datepicker for each new element). E.G:

```
$(".addOffer").click(function(){
    //Code to add an offer (ensuring it has the class .latest)
    $("#offers").append("<input type='text' name='datePicker' class='datepickerNew latest' />");

    //Add date picker
    $("#offers .latest.datepickerNew").datepicker().removeClass('latest');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. 
My resolution was to add `z-index` in `.date-picker` of `datePicker.css`

```
.date-picker {
position: absolute;
z-index:1000;/*********** MY Change *************/
font-size: 1em;
color: #CCC;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;

border: 1px solid #444;
border-radius: 2px;
margin: 6px 0;
background: #222;
box-shadow: 8px 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);}
```

And with this change the Date Picker started displaying.

Answer (score 0):

find and **remove** it if you has something like this!

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is super old but I ran into the issue and came up with an elegant solution based on the jQuery documentation. Using the onClose event built in the datePicker api, I just remove the hasDatepicker class.

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onClose: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hasDatepicker");
 }});
```

Keep in mind, that ideally you have a unique id for each element, sometimes this is not possible.